# How can I uglyfy selected JS?

Tags: javascript, gulp, unminify

I'm using [generator-gulp-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp), but I want to just selected Javascript files that build in minified form. How can I edit `gulpfile.js` ? Here is the `html` task. I think I should edit this task.

```
gulp.task('html', ['views','styles'], function () {
  var assets = $.useref.assets({searchPath: ['.tmp', 'app', '.']});

  return gulp.src(['app/*.html', '.tmp/*.html'])
   .pipe(assets)
   .pipe($.if('*.js', $.uglify()))
   .pipe($.if('*.css', $.csso()))
   .pipe(assets.restore())
   .pipe($.useref())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only want to uglify js files here is a simple task :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/js/*.js') //get all js
      pipe(concat('main.js')) //concat all js in a single file
      pipe(uglify()) //minify js
      pipe(gulp.dest('dist')); //output js in dist folder

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('app/js/*', ['js']);
});
```